Why does Car-Parrinello molecular dynamics not need an SCF procedure at every time-step?
Reading the various terms of the Lagrangian in CPMD I'm trying to understand why there is not an SCF procedure hidden there.
In fact, it seems to me like the second term of the Euler-Lagrange equation is similar (except for the variational minimization) to that of Born-Oppenheimer Molecular Dynamics, also if it is placed equal to the "force" due to the fictitious mass.
I'm missing this essential and maybe obvious feature to appreciate this method.
I'm sorry for not writing the equations.
Many thanks

Related Q&A: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6609/7

An answer can be found on Physics SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/821944/why-doesnt-car-parrinello-molecular-dynamics-require-an-scf-calculation/
